# Adding Data Source To Powerbi Gateway

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource, azure-analysis-services, analysisservices, powerbi-datagateway

I built a powerbi dashboard recently, the dashboard is working perfectly but after publishing to the web i am having issues with the gateway setup on the web. This is preventing the dashboard from auto-refreshing.

The connection to the database is through Analysis Service. Below is the snapshot of the error

[Error message i got when i tried to setup the gateway](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUB20.jpg)

Comment: Is the username and pw correct? As the error is saying that it is not in the right format. Is the SSAS on premise? as you have tagged the Azure version?

Comment: The username and password are correct. It is powerbi web data source gateway setup

Comment: Could you put the error message here in a text form, so Google will be able to index it and other people with the same problem will find this?

Comment: @AntonKrug: Thanks for your response. This is the error in text form

Unable to connect: We encountered an error while trying to connect to . Details: "We could not register this data source for any gateway instances within this cluster. Please find more details below about specific errors for each gateway instance."Hide details
Activity ID: 432d7985-f7dc-46ea-8dd5-389297fc0eaa
Request ID: 5610d182-e526-f311-873f-17e8d02bf407
Cluster URI: https://wabi-north-europe-redirect.analysis.windows.net/
Status code: 400
Error Code: DMTS_PublishDatasourceToClusterErrorCode

Comment: Error Continuation:

Time: Mon Apr 19 2021 08:50:52 GMT+0100 (West Africa Standard Time)
Service version: 13.0.15854.62
Client version: 2104.1.05665-train
RenmoneyMIS_SER: Username needs to include a domain. Please use the format user@domain or domain\user and try again.